# Запись в БД при обработке нажатия на SwitchCompat

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Помогите ,пожалуйста, разобраться с ситуацией.
Использую `SwitchCompat vibro_switch;` для включения/отключения вибрации в приложении.
Положение ВКЛ - иконка `vibro_image` меняется на включено, положение ВЫКЛ - меняется на иконку отключено.
Проблем со сменой иконки нет, здесь все работает на ура.

Проблема с сохранением состояния в БД:
`getNameUser()` - заменяла на текст хардкодом, даже выводила в лог - имя выводится, ошибка явно не в этом.
Выносила запись в БД в любое абстрактное место, например при старте всего приложения - запись происходит так же без проблем.

Из самого класса осуществляется несколько обращений к БД на чтение и запись и все ок.
Отсюда делаю вывод, что проблем с обращением к БД нету, иначе ошибка выскочила в другом месте.

Проблема только с записью в БД из переключателя.

На всякий случай запрос на обновление записи:

```
@Query("UPDATE SettingsAll SET VibroMode = :vibro WHERE UserSettings = :user")
void updateVibro(String vibro, String user); //обновляем статус настройки вибрации
```

Обработчик нажатия на переключатель:

```
    public void settings_vibro(View v){
        if (vibro_switch.isChecked()) {
            vibro_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vibro);
            dataBase.settingsAllDAO().updateVibro("on", getNameUser());
        }else
            vibro_image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.vibro_off);
            dataBase.settingsAllDAO().updateVibro("off", getNameUser());
    } //настройка вибро
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем у меня ошибка и где я не права?

Comment: А проблема то в чём?

Comment: Запись в бд не происходит. Вообще

Comment: То есть вы открыли базу (https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database), а записи там нет? И никаких ошибок в логах, приложение не упало? Тогда должно быть проблема в запросе: `UPDATE` выполняется только если условие верно, то есть в таблице есть строка с совпадающим значением в поле `UserSettings`

Comment: Верно. Я все понимаю, но ошибок ни каких нет. Проблема записи только из обработчика нажатия. ПРи нажатии меняются иконки у приложения, пишется в Log.d. Update  создается если проивзодить запись не из этого метода, а из любого друого

Comment: Ну тогда я не вижу причин, по которым запись может не происходить. Ставьте точку останова в этот метод, запускайте приложение под дебаггером и пошагово смотрите что происходит, какие значения в переменных.

Comment: Хм.. А у вас `else` без блока и в проекте тоже, или сюда так скопировали? В таком виде у вас в базу должно записываться `"off"` в любом случае, так как последняя строка вне условия.

Comment: Вот я дура.... Спасибо огромное!))))))))))))